# Clean data tweets

Tags: java, twitter

Why when this is being run, the tweet is being cleaned by the sentiment value no longer appears. The sentiment value appears if the cleanData method is not called. Does anyone know if this is due to stanford libraries which are being used and imported?

```
public class WhatToThink {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String topic = "Brussels";
        ArrayList<String> tweets = TweetManager.getTweets(topic);
        NLP.init();

        tweets = cleanData(tweets);

        for (String tweet : tweets) {
            tweets = cleanData(tweets);
            System.out.println(tweet + " : " + NLP.findSentiment(tweet));
        }


    }

    public static ArrayList<String> cleanData(ArrayList<String> tweets) {
        ArrayList<String> newTweets = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator itr = tweets.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String tweet = itr.next().toString();

            //convert tweet to lower case
            tweet = tweet.toLowerCase();

            //remove urls
            tweet = tweet.replaceAll("((www\\.[^\\s]+)|(https?://[^\\s]+))", "URL");

            //remove user names
            tweet = tweet.replaceAll("@[^\\s]+", "ATUSER");

            //remove # from hash tag
            tweet = tweet.replaceAll("#", "");

            //remove punctuation
            tweet = tweet.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");

            System.out.println(tweet);
        }
        return newTweets;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cleanData` returns an empty `ArrayList`. Try adding `tweet` to `newTweets`.

I strongly advice that you write at least some basic unit tests. This would have been caught with even the most basic of tests on cleanData.